# Can AtomicBoolean replace volatile boolean?

Tags: java, concurrency

Given following code, in which I check a boolean value `isInitialised` before running some code. if instead of
`private static volatile boolean isInitialised;`, I use
`private static final AtomicBoolean isInitialised = new AtomicBoolean(false);`,
it should achieve the same outcome and even the performance difference is negligible?

```java
public class DclSingleton {

    private static volatile boolean isInitialised;
    //private static final AtomicBoolean isInitialised = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static void doInit() {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            synchronized (DclSingleton.class) {
                if (!isInitialised) {
                    // do init
                    
                    isInitialised = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

And if I do use `AtomicBoolean`, would following code achieve the same?

```java
public class DclSingleton {

    // private static volatile boolean isInitialised;
    private static final AtomicBoolean isInitialised = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static void doInit() {
        if (isInitialised.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            // do init            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two important differences between your two examples.

First, the obvious: The `doInit()` method in your first example only sets `isInitialized=true` *after* initializing the singleton.  But, in your second example, it sets the `AtomicBoolean` instance to `true` *before* it initializes the singleton. That could be a problem if a second thread obtains a reference to the singleton after the flag has been set, but before the initialization has completed.

The second problem is less obvious: There is no synchronization after the flag is set in your second example. Nothing establishes a *happens before* relationship between the initialization code and anything that happens in some other thread. In your first example, the initialization *happens before* `isInitialized=true`, and `isInitialized=true` *happens before* any other thread tests `if(!isInitialized)...`

In your second example, if two threads concurrently call `doInit()`, The Atomic operation ensures that only one of them can enter the initialization code. But even if the winner, by pure chance, actually completes the initialization code before* the other thread starts to use the singleton object, there still is no formal *happens before* relationship between the first thread doing the initialization and the second thread accessing the singleton.

---

* "before" in *real time* (a.k.a., wall clock time). If some event A *actually* happens before event B in real time, but there is no formal *happens before* relationship between the two events, then it is possible for some other thread to see the effects of those two events *as if* they happened in a different order.

Comment: in plain english : the second variant is very broken. I like your answer. what people seem to not get (a bit) that `volatile` is only an optimization in the DCL, it is not mandatory

Comment: In the first example, if I used AtomicBoolean without volatile, I suppose it should still work fine as ‘synchronised’ will also enforce happens-before?

Comment: @wayne show an _actual_ example of what you mean and then we can reason about it, guessing with these kind of things is very dangerous. Even your initial examples are not that good, you never show who is the reader, what get initializes, etc.

Comment: @Eugene more codes here https://app.codingrooms.com/w/Qp3bwUTSKv7w. The real use case is that I want to init some cache in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. The visibility is guarantee.

AtomicBoolean is similar to synchronized but it's considered to outperformed than synchronize due to compareAndSwap utility of CPU cache.

The small difference is it's not make sure the order of execution between multiple threads while synchronized can.

Answer (score 1):

AtomicXxxx wraps a volatile so they are basically same, the difference is that it provides higher level operations such as CompareAndSwap which is used to implement increment.